# How to make my buttons do different things with C# in Unity?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I currently have some code to that puts some buttons on the screen via an array and I assign the textures in the inspector. The problem is that I don't know how to make for example button 1 quit the game, button 2 go to the next level and button 3 to load an image. Could someone explain to me what I need to do to make the individual buttons do different things when they are clicked? (The second array is for my buttons on the right side of the screen)

This is what my code looks like right now:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class UI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D[] parts;
    public Texture2D[] extra;
        int buttonHeight, buttonWidth;
    int x, y;
    int width, height;

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; ++i) 
        {
            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (x - 35, i * (height + 97), width + 300, height + 90), parts [i]))
            Debug.Log ("Clicked button " + i);
            //if (GUI.Button (new Rect (0, i * (buttonHeight + 20), buttonWidth + 100, buttonHeight + 100), textures [i]))
       }
       for (int x = 0; x < extra.Length; ++x) 
       {
           if (GUI.Button (new Rect (x + 800, x * (height + 140), width + 300, height + 120), extra [x]))

           Debug.Log ("Clicked button " + x);
           if (extra [0] && Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")) 
           {
               Application.CaptureScreenshot ("Screenshot.png");
               Debug.Log ("Screen captured");
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class UI : MonoBehaviour {

public Texture2D[] parts;
public Texture2D[] extra;
public string[] actions;
int buttonHeight, buttonWidth;
int x, y;
int width, height;

void OnGUI ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; ++i) 
    {
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (x - 35, i * (height + 97), width + 300, height + 90), parts [i]))
            Execute(actions[i]);
        //if (GUI.Button (new Rect (0, i * (buttonHeight + 20), buttonWidth + 100, buttonHeight + 100), textures [i]))
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < extra.Length; ++x) 
    {
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (x + 800, x * (height + 140), width + 300, height + 120), extra [x]))

            Debug.Log ("Clicked button " + x);
        if (extra [0] && Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")) 
        {
            Application.CaptureScreenshot ("Screenshot.png");
            Debug.Log ("Screen captured");
        }
    }
}

void Execute(string action) {
    switch (action) {
    case "exit":
        Application.Quit();
        break;
    case "next":
        // Load next level..
        Debug.Log("next");
        break;
    }
}
```

}